# How to sort months in the correct order Jan-Dec Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, sorting, monthcalendar

I would like to have some help to put the calendar days in the matplot graphics in order from Jan - Dec. My code is below. The months are in a pandas dataframe.

Code

```
month_df = df.groupby(['month_name']).count()

month_df = month_df.sort_values(by="month_name",ascending=True)

month_df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(month_df["month_name"])
```

Comment: Since it's a string sorting, normally they are sorted by alphabetical order. The only way to sort from Jan to Dec is to create a list of correct orders and use that as indices to sort the rows (AFAIK).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment, you can do something like

```
order = "Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Sep Dec".split() 

month_df = df.groupby(['month_name']).count()
month_df = month_df.loc[order]
```

Comment: The following error shows up when I use your advice: KeyError: "Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported. The following labels were missing: Index(['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'Jun',\n       ...\n
'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],\n      dtype='object', name='month_name', length=11). See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-lis
tlike"

Comment: I just gave a generic example since you didn't provide any example data for your cases. It seems like you are using different naming for months than what I was using.